# What formula to use in an MS Word (English UI) field to get the sum in words in Russian?

Tags: microsoft-word, localization

I've got English UI in Windows and in MS Office applications. But I prepare a document in Word in Russian. I tried to

1. Create a field via Ctrl+F9
2. In the new field I've entered

   **=235555 *CardText \l 1049**
3. Pressed Alt+F9 to show the field values. Got

   **!Syntax Error, L**

What is wrong in the formula? I cannot find any clear official description of this approach.

**UPD**
**\l** is a locale switch ([official MS Office docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Field-codes-Citation-field-18b0c6a3-c0e6-4f76-a541-478f389b287d?CorrelationId=76363317-ec00-4e18-a4a7-89c1823e0ea2&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA010215707)). Perhaps, it only works for citation fields. But I hope there is a way to localize the number-word conversion, too.

Comment: What is this "L" - does it mean a "long"? Have you tried without this format:=235555 * "CardText" \ 1049  ?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MS Word automatically detects the language of the document and outputs the number in words in the detected language. Even in MS Word with English MUI I created a new document, started to type in Russian from scratch and then inserted fields with a formula like

```
=155587\*CardText
```

and the output was in Russian.
But still, it is strange. I created the question because at first I had a document with a few English sentences, and it led to a confusion.

Anyway it would be better to set the locale of the output explicitly in this case.